# How to localize Stimulus JS value using i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, rails-i18n, stimulusjs

I am working on rails 6 application where I'm trying to store all displayed strings in locales files. I have a Stimulus controller named `countdown_controller.js`:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {

  static values = {
    message: { type: String, default: "Deal closed!" }
  }
}
```

`en.yml`:

```
en:
 deals:
   status:
     closed: "Deal closed!"
```

I want to use `I18n.t("deals.status.closed")` as a value for `messageValue` in `countdown_controller.js` instead of directly writing the string. I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply converting `countdown_controller.js` to `countdown_controller.js.erb` worked for me. Then I used interpolation to inject the `I18n.t("deals.status.closed")` as follows:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {

  static values = {
    message: { type: String, default: "<%= I18n.t('deals.status.closed') %>" }
  }
}
```

P.S. I was getting an error initially as I changed the comment to use ruby syntax which begins with `#` instead of JS syntax which begins with `//`.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to send the translations as part of the Stimulus controller element dataset, so it's available on `connect`. In my case there is more than one, so I send a hash from the view or the helper, like this:

```rb
localizations = {
  processing_images: :suggestions_processing_images.t,
  processing_image: :suggestions_processing_image.t,
  processing_results: :suggestions_processing_results.t,
  error: :suggestions_error.t
}.to_json

button_tag(:suggest_names.l,
           type: :button, 
           data: { localization: localizations,
                   controller: "suggestions",
                   action: "suggestions#suggestNames" })
```

```js
// javascript/controllers/suggestions_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="suggestions"
export default class extends Controller {
  initialize() {
    this.localized_text = {}
  }
  connect() {
    Object.assign(this.localized_text,
      JSON.parse(this.element.dataset.localization));
  }
}
```